# What to do when no one answers your question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, unanswered-questions

Yes i know that one answer is to wait. But if you want answer urgently then what to do? What are alternatives?

Comment: We don't deliver "urgent" answers.

Comment: Okay I apologize

Comment: Ask [in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) though getting an immediate answer will depend on who is in the chat room at the time.

Comment: Well thank you, actually i was in haste. Will you please refer to the question I asked, I am not getting its answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353847/

Comment: @PranjalRana One other reason could be that the question you cite has very little to do with physics.

Comment: When it comes to an answer about physics, the amount to which someone else's urgency is relevant to me (or others in general, really) is directly proportional to the sum of both how much I am being paid to give said answer and how many people's well-being is dependent on a timely answer from me. My point? Don't go to volunteers for a fast answer. Try paying someone for a faster answer or putting someone's safety in jeopardy until an answer is delivered (although I don't condone the latter)

Comment: @gennardo, if you see, my question given above deals with gravity actually so it is physics